# How to solve page not found error in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-ajax-selects

I have a list of multiple projects on my page, and each project have a contact use button, if a user click on `contact us` page then it will open a popup form, and I am doing this using Ajax. But whenever i click on the button it displays page not found in `Network`(After debug). Please let me know How I can solve thsi issue.

Here is my `urls.py` file...

```
re_path('ajax/datadis/<int:pk>/$', views.dataview, name='dataview'),
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def dataview(request, id):
    template_name = 'page/ajax/popup.html'
    return render(request, template_name)
```

here is my `index.html` file code...

```
<ul class="product-rating">
    <button title="Enquire for {{i.name}}" id="id_{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="projectDetail({{i.id}})" data-url="{% url 'appname:projectview' i.id %}">Contact Us</button>
</ul>
```

here is my Ajax Code...Which open the Popup Form...

```
</script>
function projectDetail(id){
var html = '';
var modalDiv = $("#modalData");
$.ajax({
url: "{% url 'appname:dataview' %}"+id,
type:"GET",
dataType:"HTML",
success: function(res) {
 modalDiv.html(res);
$("#exampleModal").modal("show");
 }
});
}
</script>
```

here is my popup model code...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modalData">
      <p>{{i.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the `error` which I am getting in console.

```
Page not found (404)    
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/datadis/%3Cint:pk%3E/161
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re_path` has has a different syntax. it looks like path is sufficient for this url.

```
path('ajax/datadis/<int:pk>/', views.dataview, name='dataview'),
```

the url tag in the template will expect the id as a parameter.

```
{% url 'appname:dataview' id %}",
```

Comment: I am getting this error after changing from `re_path` to `path`..
`Reverse for 'dataview' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ajax/datadis/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`

Comment: This `(?P<pk>[0-9]+)` IS the correct syntax for `re_path`, the example above is mixed w/ `path` style.